# Oracle: TRUNCATE sometimes takes ages

Tags: performance, oracle

Usually, truncating a table takes 5-10 seconds. But when several people work on the same DB instance (but different tables), the operation can take more than an hour. How do I debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locks on the table or on data dictionary resources used by the 'truncate table' command could cause this.  The system could possibly be waiting around for a resource to be released before it can do the truncate.

Check whether the session is blocked waiting for a lock to be released.

Take a look at the queries described in [orafaq.com/node/854](http://www.orafaq.com/node/854) or [dba-oracle.com/t_locked_rows_user_locks.htm](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_locked_rows_user_locks.htm) to find out which locks might be blocking.

Comment: Can you tell me some SQL that I can run to see what is happening?

Comment: I don't have any to hand but there are lots of Oracle resources on the web with scripts that do this type of thing.  Take a look at the queries described in http://www.orafaq.com/node/854 or http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_locked_rows_user_locks.htm for some examples.  Google is your friend here.

Answer (score 0):

When using SAN storage, the `filesystemio_options` parameter setting should be reviewed.  Setting the parameter to `SETALL` or `ASYNCH` alleviates log file sync waits during the truncate execution.

On a busy system, running additional DB writers is recommended as well.